# Trouble with finding java in dcm4chee

Tags: java, netbeans, dcm4che

I had dcm4chee set up for some time using Java 6 but I added Java 7. I haven't looked at dcm4chee in quite some time so I'm not sure when it stopped working. I'm running Ubuntu 13.10. When I run ./run.sh I get

```
=========================================================================

 JBoss Bootstrap Environment

 JBOSS_HOME: /home/ilan/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-2.17.2-mysql

 JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/java

 JAVA_OPTS: -Dprogram.name=run.sh -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m    -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=0 -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dapp.name=dcm4chee -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.library.path=/home/ilan/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-2.17.2-mysql/bin/native

 CLASSPATH: /home/ilan/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-2.17.2-mysql/bin/run.jar

=========================================================================

./run.sh: 217: ./run.sh: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/java: not found
```

It is true that at /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin there is no java, but only javaws. In java-7-openjdk there is the java file it is looking for. I set JAVA_HOME to point to java7 but it is picking up java6.

I use Netbeans for my java programs and I still need java 6 for some older projects. Netbeans has no problems with my java but dcm4chee is having problems.

To get the value of JAVA_HOME I used

```
ls -al /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Apr 22  2013 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
```

This indicates that JAVA_HOME is pointing to java7, so why is dcm4chee still trying to go to java6?

In short, can anyone give me advice on what I need to do to get dcm4chee up and running?

Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: I missed seeing that in addition to run.sh there was also run.config. The run.config had the export command to JDK6. It still isn't up and running, but at least that problem is solved.

Comment: I finally got it to fly. My last problem was that I was using 
http://localhost:8080/dcm4chee-web/ which should be http://localhost:8080/dcm4chee-web3/